how to pass a file to a container
I have a usecase wherein I need to pass path to a file as an env variable to my java app running in k8s.
env:
 name: INPUT
 value: /path/to/input.txt

App would read the file from location specified.
So I need to ensure that when pod starts, this file is passed to container at location provided above.
I understand that using volumes and volumemounts, we can do this.
spec:
 containers:
 - name: myapp
   image: myapp:latest
   volumeMounts:
   - name: xyz
     mountPath: /app/config
...
...
spec:
 volumes:
 - name: xyz

I am not very clear how would this work.
What location mounthPath represents in this whole arrangement?
And how to I make input.txt available to all this setup in kubernetes?
Edit: mountPath represents the location container knows. So app can access it.

So, in your Kubernetes Pod definition, when you define a volumeMounts section inside a container spec, mountPath is the location inside the container where the volume (including your file or files) will be accessible. Your application can read from and write to this path just like it were a local path inside the container.
To pass the input.txt file to your application, you'll need to create a volume that contains this file and then mount this volume into your container at the desired location. There are multiple ways to create volumes in Kubernetes, such as using a ConfigMap, a secret, or directly mounting a host path.
For something like an input.txt file, a ConfigMap is often appropriate unless the file contains sensitive information (in which case, you would want to use a Secret).
To use a configmap, first cd into the directory containing your input.txt on your local machine.
Then, use kubectl to create a ConfigMap from this file:
kubectl create configmap input-file --from-file=input.txt -n your-namespace

This command will create a ConfigMap named input-file which contains your input.txt.
Then update your deployment YAML to use this ConfigMap:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /app/config  # Your app reads the file from /app/config/input.txt
        env:
        - name: INPUT
          value: /app/config/input.txt
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: input-file  # The name of the ConfigMap created earlier

Let me break this down further:

The ConfigMap input-file is mounted into the container at the path /app/config.
Inside the container, your application can access the file at /app/config/input.txt.
The environment variable INPUT is set to /app/config/input.txt, which is the path your application can use to access the file.

This ensures that when your pod starts, the input.txt file is already mounted at the specified location inside the container, and your application can immediately begin to read from it.
Once you deploy this, you can verify that everything is set up correctly by exec-ing into the running container:
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -n your-namespace -- /bin/bash

Then, check that the input.txt file exists at the correct location by using:
cat /app/config/input.txt

Hope this helps.
